# Split 1 row to multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, database-design, relational-database

Data

```
1; from 0; to 1; 5% ; boulder; 10% ; sand; 20%; silt
```

The output should look like this:

```
1; from 0; to 1;  5% ; boulder

1; from 0; to 1; 10%; sand

1; from 0; to 1; 20% silt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `unpivot`.  However, the simplest method if the data is not too big is just to use `union all`:

```
select station, "from(m)", "to(m)", "ob.1" as Materials, Percent1 as Percent
from table t
union all
select station, "from(m)", "to(m)", "ob.2" as Materials, Percent2 as Percent
from table t
union all
select station, "from(m)", "to(m)", "ob.3" as Materials, Percent3 as Percent
from table t;
```

Note that you have three columns called `Percent`.  That is not allowed in a SQL table, so I assume they have different names.

Another method using `cross join` or `unpivot` would generally have better performance if your table is really larger.

Comment: thank you very much it worked.  However I was trying to add a where clause to filter the result but it doesn't work.  How should I do it??  Thanks!

Comment: @user3478071 . . . Either add the `where` clause to all three subqueries or use a subquery:  `select * from (<query in answer>) t where . . . `.

Comment: please give an example for the sub-query as I cannot really make it work.  Thanks again